# Is there a shorthand way to assign a group of variables to each of the values of an array in php?

Tags: php, syntax

In perl I can write

```
($var1, $var2, $var3) = split(/:/, "foo:bar:blarg")
```

to split a string by colon and assign each array element to $var1, $var2 and $var3. Is there a similar syntax for this in php? I have to use the variables in a lot of my code so I want them to have meaningful names, and writing variable assignment code like

```
$array = split(/:/, "foo:bar:blarg");
$var1 = $array[0];
$var2 = $array[1];
//etc
```

is tedious when i have to do this a lot.

Comment: split() is for regular expression. if you just want to "split" by :, use explode() instead. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP has the [`list` language construct](http://docs.php.net/list) to do that.

```
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = split(":", "foo:bar:blarg");
```